# no migration via terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I can't migrate new columns in my database **via the terminal and RoR**.
I only get the first step:

```
**$ rails g migration add_online_to_posts online:boolean**

Running via Spring preloader in process 13406
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20170808141302_add_online_to_posts.rb
```

Afterwards nothing works:

```
**$ rails db:migrate**
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationVersionError: 

Multiple migrations have the version number 20170725122210.

/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1257:in `validate'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1123:in `initialize'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `new'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1007:in `up'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:985:in `migrate'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:171:in `migrate'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/projets/RoR_formation/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I can handle columns via the IDE:
[image]

But when I do :

```
**$ Status   Migration ID    Migration Name**
  up     20170725122210  Create posts table
  up     20170726082500  Rename post title to intitule
  up     20170728143925  Create categories
  up     20170807110617  ********** NO FILE **********
 down    20170808113533  Add slug to posts
```

Comment: How did you create your migration files? Did you use a generator, or did you copy and edit migration files? Migration files have to be uniquely versioned.

Comment: indeed I used a generator via the terminal. But for the steps of the tutorial, I deleted the file(s)  manually

Answer (score 0):

You've already run a migration with the prefix `20170725122210` (and it looks like you may have also deleted it). For a quick fix, change your newest migration to `20170725122211` (or any other number that isn't in your schema migrations table). You may also want to run `rails db:schema:dump` and inspect the output of `db/schema.rb` for tables that are not present in your migrations.

Comment: indeed I used a generator via the terminal. But for the steps of the tutorial, I deleted the file(s) manually.    When I run  ** rails db:schema:dump ** it makes nothing.    . Therefore I couldn't inspect the output of db/schema.rb.  I refactorized my newest migration to 20170725122211  I also notified that Rubymine allows to run and to create db migrate from the IDE. May I use this ?option?